# Replace a string of text from the dom with PHP

Tags: php, dom

```
<label for="options_958_1" class="custom-option-label multi 
options_958_1_label  height-cell- 27" data-column="column-height" data- 
column-parent="column-parent-height"><span class="default- 
title">6200°</span>:<span data-option-id="958" class="custom-option- 
sku">27</span></label>`
```

I am trying to access the value of 6200° from the dom and then replace it with new text.

For example I would want to replace 6200 with 8500.

This is what the code I have been using after doing some searching but still very new to php and cant get the value.

$kelvin2700 = find('span[class=".options_958_1_label"]');

Comment: You want to use a "DOM parser" for this. Multiple are available, "simpledom" is a well known one.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your correctly, something like this should get you in the right direction:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><label for="options_958_1" class="custom-option-label multi options_958_1_label  height-cell- 27" data-column="column-height" data-column-parent="column-parent-height">   <span class="default-title">6200°</span>   <span data-option-id="958" class="custom-option-  sku">27</span></label>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$temp = $xpath->query('//label/span[@class="default-title"]');
echo $temp[0]->textContent;
```

Output:

```
6200°
```